# Default permissions for new objects in the schema

Tags: permissions, db2, database-schema, ibm-midrange

I'm working on a **DB2 for i** database (aka DB2/400), on a schema (library) named S.

Inside schema S, I create database tables, procedures etc. with user A. I need that also user B has all privileges on such new objects. So I granted all privileges to users A and B on schema S. But new objects don't inherit them!

So I tried many configurations: on System i Navigator I played with authorization lists, "New Objects" button on permissions dialog for schema S... but nothing worked.

**How can I set kind of default permissions to be automatically inherited by new objects created in my schema?**

The only working alternative I know is remembering to `grant` privileges to user B every time I create an object. Not so smart...

Comment: There are no "default permissions". You do have to grant privileges explicitly for each new object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have IBM i 7.1.

If I create table using 5250 emulator, inside STRSQL, it works, inheriting schema authorization list.

If I create table using iSeries Navigator V5R4M0 (neither with right click on Tables > New > Table, nor with cwbundbs.exe), it doesn't work. Authorization list is not inherited...

So it seems to be a bug in iSeries Navigator. Maybe someone with a newer version of it could confirm us if this has been fixed.

Full details in the [chat with @BuckCalabro](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30342/discussion-between-bluish-and-buck-calabro).

Comment: Examine the connections inside iSeries Navigator it's probably using *SQL when *Server would give the desired results.  Leave nothing to chance.  A better practice is to specifically grant and revoke authorities when you create a table.

Comment: @danny117 Thanks, can you specify where this setting is located, please?

Comment: You start the run a sql script.  Then in the script window. select connection/jdbc settins.  Then on the format tab you can change the naming convention to *sys..  I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Security is a large topic.  It's normally handled by an administrator; someone who is aware of the larger ramifications of altering permissions to libraries.

There are several related settings to consider.  Since you're trying to secure individual objects, you probably have restricted public authority either by setting QSECURITY to *EXCLUDE, or changing the library's CRTAUT to *EXCLUDE.

If we want ALL newly created objects in this library to have the same authority, consider an authorization list.  I know that you said you played wuth authorization lists, but you didn't specify what you did.

Create an authorization list.  Authorise user A and B to the authorization list.  CHGLIB myschema CRTAUT(myautl).  Now each object in myschema will have the same authority.

Comment: Thanks Buck! This is what I tried (`CHGLIB LIB(MYLIB) CRTAUT(MYAUTLIST)`), but, when I create new table in MYLIB, it doesn't aquire permissions from MYAUTLIST. It's strange...

Comment: EDTOBJAUT MYLIB/MYFILE *FILE  What do you see for *PUBLIC - I see *AUTL.

Comment: OK, do a DSPLIB MYLIB.  What do you see for 'Create authority' (upper left)?  I see MYAUTL.

Comment: Well the OS is doing everything as expected.  EDTOBJAUT MYAUTL *AUTL  Are users A and B both there, and granted the authority you want?  What is *PUBLIC?  Is user A part of a group profile?  A supplementary profile?

Comment: Thanks again! `EDTOBJAUT MYAUTL *AUTL` says: *PUBLIC: *EXCLUDE, A: *ALL, B: *ALL. A and B belong to the same group profile. A has "user class" `*SECOFR`, B has `*PGMR`.

Comment: So looking at one of the new tables, what can A do that B cannot?  What is the specific error message?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30342/discussion-between-bluish-and-buck-calabro)

Comment: Best might be to assign a group profile to both A and B. Then put the group profile on the authorization list, unless A and B actually require different authorities to the objects. If different authorities are needed, I'd possibly use two group profiles. By using an authorization list, future authority changes won't need to allocate the *FILE objects; no locks will get in the way. And by using group profiles, any new future users can be granted all needed authorities simply by adding them to the matching groups. Similarly, removing authorities is just as easy. (And A is a *SECOFR??)